# How to disable Nautilus option "Picture CD"

Tags: gnome, nautilus, shotwell

Since recent update Nautilus randomly started rendering additional bar whenever I go into  hard drives other then the drive with Ubuntu. [The bar is showing option to do 'Picture CD', that is to do image library search with shootwell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3JKN.png). I'd like to have this bar removed, but since I have no idea how it was enabled in the 1st place without my permission, I can't figure out what conf file should be tweaked.